# foreach возвращает дважды результат

Tags: php

сообщество. Не пойму то ли баг, то ли фича.

```
// router.php
public function match()
    {
     // other code
        foreach ($this->routes AS $route) {
            if (true)) {
                // other code
                // Если все нормально вернет Route и механизм отработает
                // Но в лог попадет второй return 3;
                echo 2;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return 3;
    }
    // далее в index.php
    $router->run($router->match(), $di);
```

В error.log сыпятся ошибки

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to system\\Router::run() must be an instance of system\\Route, boolean given, called in ... system\\Router->run(true, Object(system\\DependencyInjector))\n#1 {main} ...
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to system\\Router::run() must be an instance of system\\Route, integer given, called in ... system\\Router->run(3, Object(system\\DependencyInjector))\n#1 {main} ...
```

То есть оба возврата выполняются и строка выводится. Есть мысли по этому поводу? Код вызывается только один раз, break не подействует.
UPD: Если убрать строгий тип run(*Route* $route, Di $di) ошибка пропадает как и полагалось 
UPD: Банально не отрабатывается правило в htaccess на предмет favicon.ico . Запрос не находит картинку и сыплет ошибки. Вопрос решен

Comment: Разумеется, 2 возврата означают 2 вызова функции

Comment: Так у меня match нигде не используется кроме старта, не могу отследить этого

Comment: а если `$router->match()` в другую какую функцию вставить как параметр, будет тоже 2 раза запускаться?

Comment: Если вы используете фреймворк какой, у вас могут быть подзапросы внутри приложения. Здесь явно два вызова `index.php`

Comment: Быстренько добросил код выше run():  `function test(\system\Route $r){
    debug($r);
}

test($router->match());` В логе ошибка в test(NULL)